# pandas how to set default value for emty row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an datframe like this:

```
product_name  image url
 product A
 product B   https://...
 product c
```

here product A and B don't have any image url. How I can set an defult image url for product A and product c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using np.where, you can assign a default URL whereever the image URL is null

```
df['image_url'] = np.where(df['image_url'].isna(), 'http://default.url', df['image_url'])
df
```

```
    product_name    image_url
0   product A   http://default.url
1   product B   https://...
2   product c   http://default.url
```